# Can't get names of running applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am trying to get name of running applications (mozila, visual studio etc.) I try code bellow but my I get "Access Denied" exception. I don't know how to solve this?

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

               foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
               {
                   try
                   {
                       foreach (ProcessModule pm in p.Modules)
                       {
                           sb.Append("Image Name:\t" +
                               pm.ModuleName.ToString()
                               + Environment.NewLine);

                           sb.Append("File Path:\t\t" +
                               pm.FileName.ToString() +
                               Environment.NewLine);

                           sb.Append("Memory Size:\t" +
                               pm.ModuleMemorySize.ToString() +
                               Environment.NewLine);

                           sb.Append("Version:\t\t" +
                               pm.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion.ToString() +
                               Environment.NewLine);

                           sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                       }
                   }
                   catch { }
               }
```

Comment: Instead of that empty catch put the exception message and stacktrace in a string and show us the stacktrace, or use a logger class anyway. Avoid empty useless catches like this as much as you can :)

Comment: Check for security issues, like: are you admin, is UAC turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ok, this is privilege problem.

Perhaps you are trying to get this under user account that has no privileges to access this API.

There are group called something like *performance counter user*, add your **application** account to *admin* or *performance counter user* group.

If you are using the ASP.NET, ASPNET account (configured by default) has no privileges to access this API.

Comment: I am using windows service. UAC is turned off. I am administrator. But I think of something else. This windows 7 that I run is installed on virtual machine on my MAC OS X. Is it possible that this is problem somehow?

Comment: Yes, you are admin, but which user account running your service? Start services.msc, look at "Log on as" column for your service.

Comment: Log On As column for my service is 'local service'

Comment: You need to grant privileges to "local service". Or change user account: Run services.msc, select your service, right click choose properties, tab "Log on", button "Browse", choose admin account, enter credentials, click ok...

Answer (score 0):

Ah I solved. I changed account type from 'local service' to 'local system'.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, you should add this as a comment on Branimir's answer, as you've already accepted it, and he appears to have helped you.